# How to get the data input(user input) from main page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have make a login page that have two input field, name and matrix no. After the user input the name and matrix no and click the login button, the system will direct the user to second page .. On this page, I want to get and use the data input from login page, which is matrix no and name .. how do I get it the name and matrix no from login page and use it on second page? .. I'm still new in javascript

Comment: some code can explain your problem in far better way.

Comment: Quite hard to help you without at least a code snippet.

Comment: I'm really sorry .. since I don't know how to do it, I can't even give any code for reference .. I'm jst trying to get the data that I input in my login page(name and matrix no) and use it on my second page using javascript, either it is possible or not a maybe a little bit of clue will be much help

Answer (score 0):

**POST data is data that is handled server side. And Javascript is on client side. So there is no way you can read a post data using JavaScript**. Unless your form is sent as a GET request, you won't be able to get that data back on the client side.

Comment: Actually i just making a simple website for my assignment using javascript, css and html .. I just want to know maybe in some way I could get a data from login page? .. or there's really no way for me to get it?

Comment: I've heard about "Javascript Variable Passing" .. will it help me?

Comment: when you send your form, send the form method attribute to "get". You'll be passing the variables to via the get param. You'll see them in the url and so you'll be able to retrieve them using basic javascript or jQuery.